# getting label's date using python and p4v

Tags: python, perforce, label, os.system

I'm trying to get a label's date. The `cmd` command that I know is:

```
p4 labels -e the_label_name
```

The indeed gives me the following:

```
Label the_label_name 2014/06/05 00:05:13 'Created by mebel. '
```

To use python, I wrote:

```
os.system("sc labels -t -e the_label_name")
```

and what I got was:

```
Label the_label_name 2014/06/05 00:05:13 'Created by mebel. '

0
```

However, if I write

```
label = os.system("sc labels -t -e the_label_name")
```

I get that

```
label = 0
```

Do you know what am I missing?

Comment: As your first example clearly shows, the return value of the `os.system` call is `0`. This gets assigned to `label`. Per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system), consider using `subprocess` if you want to retrieve the result of the process.

Comment: Consider using the P4Python library; it makes scripting Perforce calls much easier.

Comment: You could also use the -G global option, which "causes all output (and batch input for form commands with -i) to be formatted as marshalled Python dictionary objects. This is most often used when scripting." See http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/global.options.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this:

```
label = os.popen("sc labels -e the_label_name")
label = label.read()
```

That fixed everything...

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system), the return value is the exit status of the program.

If you want to retrieve the output of the program, you can use the [`check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) function from `subprocess`:

```
import subprocess
label = subprocess.check_output("sc labels -t -e the_label_name", shell=True)
```

Example:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output("shuf -n 1 /usr/share/dict/words", shell=True)
>>> 'monkey-pot\n'
```

Comment: I tried this and got: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/org/seg/tools/freeware/python/2.7.1/1/el-5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 530, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/org/seg/tools/freeware/python/2.7.1/1/el-5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 672, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/org/seg/tools/freeware/python/2.7.1/1/el-5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1202, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
`

Comment: Right, you should use `shell=True`, or pass the command as a list of strings: `['sc', 'labels', '-t', '-e', 'the_label_name']`.